# How should I setup a simple API between Rails/iOS via JSON?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails-3, json, restkit

I'm using JSON to communicate between my rails app and iOS via RestKit (Thanks Blake Watters) so I'm doing a simple `light private API` Rails-iOS integration.

It would be great t just use `respond_to` `format.json` for every controller, but I sort of ruled out this approach because I want distinct separation between API/web interface.

What's a good and DRY approach to writing a separate controller to handle API?

Right now, I'm thinking of creating a `namespace` called api and then creating controllers (e.g. shop, products) under the namespace. Each of these controllers will then have its own methods(create, destroy etc)

Comment: I just found this [Versioning your API](http://freelancing-gods.com/posts/versioning_your_ap_is) which is a good resource on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You idea about "creating a namespace called api and then creating controllers" is right. I'm using this approach in several projects. The only drawback is that anything overloading your API will overload your website as well.

You could also split API and website into two separate Rails applications. In this case make sure you are sharing your Rails models and helpers..

Comment: Thanks dude! Do you have any resource on the splitting of the API and the website into two separate apps? The googling on this part left me really confused.

Comment: It is similar to your idea of splitting controllers into name-spaces. Just make sure you can share common code. Either via git or symlink'ed  directories, gems - depends on your project.